# Adding submodule to non empty path with JGit

Tags: java, git, git-submodules, jgit

I am trying to add a submodule to a non empty folder using the JGit API class SubmoduleAddCommand and this is my code:

```java
SubmoduleAddCommand submoduleAddCommand = new SubmoduleAddCommand(repository);
submoduleAddCommand.setPath(path);
submoduleAddCommand.setName(name);
submoduleAddCommand.setURI(uri);
submoduleAddCommand.call().close();
repository.close();
```

**Destination folder** contains: Folder1, Folder2, ... and so on, and none of the previous folders is a submodule however they must not be removed. My target is to add the submodule and clone it to the **Destination folder** alongside the non-submodule folders. This results in an exception being thrown:

> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Destination path "Target_Submodule" already exists and is not an empty directory

and the submodule is neither added to the `.gitmodules` file nor cloned into the **Destination folder**.

Is there a way to add this submodule to the non-empty **Destination folder** and the `.gitmodules` file?

Answer (score 0):

Git does not allow to add a submodule into a non-empty directory.

The `SubmoduleAddCommand` will clone and checkout the specified repository into the destination path. And cloning a repository requires the destination path to be empty.

Cloning into a non-empty directory could lead to all sorts of trouble if there exist files in the destination directory that also need to be created while adding the module.